# LM386 with Gain of 40

Tags: audio, amplifier, gain, lm386

I am trying to build one of the example circuits in the [LM386 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) (any of the first 3) but with a gain of 40 rather than 20, 50 or 200.

I understand that the gain is controlled by the impedance between pins 1 and 8 and that a smaller impedance results in a larger gain. So for a gain of 40, the impedance must obviously be more than the 1.2k and 10uF in series.

So apart from trying different values for the resistor, how can I find the required impedance to get a gain of 40?

Also, why is the capacitor necessary? If it's just a question of impedance then can't the capacitor's reactance be replaced by an equivalent resistor?

Comment: Check the paragraph "Gain control" under "Application Hints" and check the feedback in the circuit diagram on the first page. I agree it is a bit unclear.

Comment: did you see this sheet for LM386 gain calculator? http://volthauslab.com/datasheets/Transistors/2N5457/LM386%20Gain%20Calculator.pdf
Unfortunately, there is no xls format but a pencil and a paper will do the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Just to add that the DC quiescent operating point is defined by the 3 circled resistors. This needs to be "left alone" when changing the AC gain hence put a 10uF in series with anything across pins 1 and 8.

Comment: Ah, so the capacitor just "resets" the circuit for DC only. Why is the gain 2 times the ratio?

Answer (score 5):

From the circuit diagram and the paragraph Gain control I derive the following two formula's:

> With pins 1 and 8 open the 1.35 kΩ resistor sets the gain at 20 (26 dB).

\$G = \dfrac{x}{150Ω + 1350Ω} = 20 \Rightarrow x = 20 \cdot (150Ω+1350Ω) = \boxed{30000}\$

> If a capacitor is put from pin 1 to 8, bypassing the 1.35 kΩ resistor, the
>   gain will go up to 200 (46 dB).

For AC the capacitor can be neglected in our formula:

\$G = \dfrac{x}{150Ω} = 200 \Rightarrow x = 200 × 150Ω = \boxed{30000}\$

The formula derived from the circuit appears to be correct because for both situations we get the same result.

Now for a Gain of 40:

\$G = \dfrac{30000}{R_p} = 40 \Rightarrow R_p = \dfrac{30000}{40} = \boxed{750Ω}\$

Where R<sub>p</sub> is the internal 1350Ω resistor in parallel with the external resistor you need to apply. Again we neglected the series capacitor:

\$R_p = 1350Ω||R_x\$

\$\dfrac{1}{R_p} = \dfrac{1}{R_x} + \dfrac{1}{R_i}\$

\$\dfrac{1}{R_x} = \dfrac{1}{R_p} - \dfrac{1}{R_i}\$

\$\dfrac{1}{R_x} = \dfrac{1}{750Ω} - \dfrac{1}{1350}\$

\$R_x \approx \boxed{ 1688Ω }\$

The nearest E12 value would be 1k5 or 1k8.

Don't forget to include the 10μF series capacitor when you actually build the circuit. Notice that the capacitor makes the circuit's response frequency dependent. A large cap (like the one proposed) will have a fairly low cut off frequency at the low frequency end.

Comment: I actually nearly derived the same formula (the first one) but \$x\$ was not exactly 30000 because I left out the \$150Ω\$ resistor. I don't really understand why it is included.

Comment: If you check the circuit diagram, it is always in series with whatever impedance is between the two Gain pins.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the above for calculating "Now for a gain of 40", the formula left out the 150 Ohm resistor.

I don't know how to type in Mathlab format, but it says

G = 30,000 / Rp

That's a mistake.  It should say

G = 30,000 / (150 + Rp)

Otherwise, shorting pins 1 and 8 would give infinite gain, instead of 200.

The answer for a gain of 40 should give Rp = 600 Ohms (1350 Ohms in parallel with the appropriate resistor), giving an answer of about 1250 Ohms for the resistor needed to set the gain.

Oddly, using this formula with the value given in the datasheet for a gain of 50 (1.2 kOhms) only gives a gain of 38.2.

So, if the datasheet is correct, the gain calculation doesn't quite work, and is not linear.  It gives both end points correctly (gain = 20 or 200), but only approximates points in between.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question) are some information about mathjax (not mathlab). Don't overdo it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked up the datasheet and came up with this. Tested it and works correctly as well.
G = (15150 + (1350*R)/(1350+R)) / (150 + (1350*R)/(1350+R)) * 2

R = Resistor in series with a 10uF capacitor between pin 1 and 8
 - pin 1 is positive
G= gain amount i.g. 50 = Output is 50*the input

As far as I know this is the simplest formula as of yet, hope it helps anybody struggling with this issue.